# how to stop repeating ajax post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with inputs validation and ajax post. I use http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

here is my code of form:

```html
<form id="order-form" class="form" action="" method="post" novalidate="true" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
  <fieldset>
    <div id="callback-type" class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default private-callback btn-primary" type="button" data-type="private">
        Private
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-default public-callback" type="button" data-type="public">
        Public
      </button>
      <input class="callback-type" type="hidden" id="callback-type-data" name="callback[type]" value="private">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset style="border: none">
    <section class="callback-time-select form-group">
      <label class="input"> <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
        <input class="callback-datetime" placeholder="<?=date('Y/m/d H:i');?>" type="text" name="callback[time]" id="callback-time" required/>
        <div class="time-clear">
          <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
        </div>
      </label>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="second callback-agent-section form-group">
      <select class="callback-agent" name="callback[user]" style="width:100%" class="select2" id="select-callback-agent" required>
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">Name</option>
      </select>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </section>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="tab-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm submit-button callback-btn-create">Set Callback</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm submit-button callback-btn-update" style="display: none;">Update Callback</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm submit-button callback-btn-remove" style="display: none;">Remove</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#dealing-modal #callback-tab .tab-actions .callback-btn-create', function(){
        $(this).closest('form').validator().submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!$('.has-error').length) {
                self.create();
            }
        });
});
```

And `self.create` method:

```
create: function() 
{
    Application.Debug("Calllback.create");
    var self    = this;
var form    = $(":input", this.window).serialize();
        form    = form + '&call_id=' + this.call.id;

$.post(Application.url+'callbacks/create', form, function(data){
    if(data.status  === true) {
    self.callback   = data.callback;
            $(".callback-btn-create",self.window).css('display','none');
            $(".callback-btn-update",self.window).css('display','inline');
            $(".callback-btn-remove",self.window).css('display','inline');
    } else {
    Application.Debug("Calllback.create - ERROR");
    }
});
}
```

I need to validate form inputs and send ajax post on click button. It initiate form submit, and when send post after form is valid.

And my problem is:

When inputs are empty and i push the button create, form validate it and i see the error text. Its fine! But when i clicked button 1 or 2 times and ect., and after i complete all inputs, method `self.create();` doing ajax post as much as times i clicked button.

Where is the problem?

Comment: You could put a boolean in a global variable and when hitting the button you set it to false or true. Change the boolean in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to disable or display none below button after click and before ajax call and vice versa after successful response.

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm submit-button callback- btn-create">Set Callback</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $submitBtn; // Lets say this is the jQuery object that contains the form button element.

$submitBtn.attr('disabled', true);

$.post().always(function () {
    $submitBtn.attr('disabled', false);
});
```

And, have some disabled styling for your button like:

```
input[type="submit"][disabled] {
    opacity: .4;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Another approach:

```
var $form; // Lets say this is the jQuery object that contains the form element.

if ($form.data('posting')) {
    return false; // We are already posting data, don't do anything.
}

$form.data('posting', true);

$.post().always(function () {
    $form.data('posting', false);
});
```

Comment: Check the other approach.